# Eclipse Ganymede Code Indenting of HTML?

Tags: html, eclipse, eclipse-wtp, autoformatting

I know I can auto-format various filetypes using `Ctrl-Shft-F`, but it seems pretty weak with HTML.

I dug through all the configuration and found nothing that allows me to set format styles for HTML, especially for nested `<DIV>` tags.

Are there any solutions within Eclipse that don't require me to doubleclick every div in the outline and hit tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to Indigo (Ganymede is over 3 years old), the formatter is much improved there.

http://eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.3.0/NewAndNoteworthy/sourceediting.php

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck with Ganymede.  Is there any other solution?

Comment: Only by installing and using some other editor that does work on Ganymede.  Why are you stuck in Ganymede?

Comment: Work computer, they're pretty locked down.